# I want to buy a VPS for my website that has around 10 K visitors per day currently - Need suggestions

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do you do Load Testing and Capacity Planning for Web Sites](https://serverfault.com/questions/350454/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-web-sites)

I have a server configuration for a VPS I am going to buy that need to serve at least 10 K visitors per day currently for my website [www.dotnetfunda.com](http://www.dotnetfunda.com).

- OS: Windows Server 2008 Standard
- RAM: 1 GB
- HDD: 40 GB
- Bandwidth: 400 GB (my current bandwidth consumption is 150 GB).

I am not sure about following

1. How much disk space will be left after installing OS and SQL Express?
2. Is the above configuration enough for the current requirement.
3. I have zeroed in to WEBECS or SoftSys after going through several hosting povides, which one is better or any other service provider better than them, any suggestions from anybody?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2008 is huge these days, off-hand, I believe it is around 15GB for the base OS and MSSQL.

Apart from that, I would be really, really reluctant to run Windows 2008 and MSSQL with 1GB RAM.

Performance is likely to be utter balls.  I would be looking a minimum of 2GB RAM.